# Persist an Bean with composite key(having IdClass)

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, ejb

OrderItem has two keys orderid and itemid. I am passing an OrderItem object. But It is throwing error: **Field 'orderItem_orderid' doesn't have a default value.**
Following is part of the code:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="OrderItem")
@IdClass(value=OrderItemPK.class)
public class OrderItem {

    @Id
    private String orderid;
    @Id
    private String itemid;

    @Column
    private String material; 

     @Column
    private String quantity; 

    public String getOrderid() {
        return orderid;
    }

    public void setOrderid(String orderid) {
        this.orderid = orderid;
    }


    public void getItemid() {
        return itemid;
    }

    public void setItemid(String orderid) {
        this.itemid = itemid;
    }

    public void getMaterial() {
        return material;
    }

    public void setMaterial(String material) {
        this.material = material;
    }


    public void getQuantity() {
        return quantity;
    }

    public void setQuantity(String quantity) {
        this.quantity = quantity;
    }



}
```

DAO:

```
public class InfoManager<T> implements InfoManagerRemote<T> {

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    @Override
    public T create(T t) throws Exception {
            entityManager.persist(t);
            return t;
    }
}
```

call:

```
OrderItem orderItem = new OrderItem();
orderItem.setOrderid("ORD000000001");
orderItem.setItemid("1");
orderItem.setMaterial("Mat1");
orderItem.setQuantity("2");
infoManagerRemote.create(orderItem);
```

It is working well when I am creating Order. Not working for orderItem.

Please help on this. I am stuck on this since 3 days.

Comment: How did you instantiate `OrderItem`? And what is the definition of the entity? Unless you post the details it is difficult to help you.

Comment: @ujulu: I have edited. Might help you.

Comment: please also post concerning entitess

Comment: So the class that it has a problem with, and you haven't posted it?!

Comment: Is there a relationship between `OrderItem` and `Order` entities? If so why don't you post the `Order` entity as well. You should post all necessary parts: `Order` entity, `OrderItemPK`. And you should check your database entries as well. For example, is there an order with the value `ORD000000001` in the database if this is field is a foreign key. I am wondering that you don't have any relationship to the `Order` entity but you are using `orderId` in the `OrderItem` entity.

Comment: Its strange .................... It is working fine after dropping all the Tables from the DB and redeployment. But the reason is still unknown. :)